# align listview from right to left

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, alignment

I'm developing with android studio.
I have a `ListView` that the elements in it are aligned from left to right and I want to align them from right to left, how can I do so?

the java class is:

```
public class ProductList extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("במבה אוסם", "בשר טחון", "קוקה קולה שישייה", "קפה עלית", "שמיר", "מילקי","רבעיית דניאלה"));
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pop_productlist);

        Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);


        /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Delete" */
        View.OnClickListener listenerDel = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };


        /** Setting the event listener for the delete button */
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);

        /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void StartCalck(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductList.this, SplitBuying.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }




}
```

and the layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ChooseStore">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you !

Comment: You are building an app in Arabic, Urdu, Hebrew, etc...  ????

Comment: Because you're using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. You have to write own layout

Comment: yea im building an app in Hebrew,how do i use a costom adapter? im new with android ...

Comment: Do you mean to display the `ListView` from bottom to top, or display the actual text in the `ArrayList` right to left?

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

```
LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom layout like 
myTextView.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:gravity="right"
android:background="#bdbdbd"/>
```

pass this layout to adapter like

```
 ArrayAdapter  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.nameOfLayout, list);
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific ? how do i pass this layout to adapter? im new with android ...

Comment: i need the custom layout to be like :simple_list_item_multiple_choice what i need to add to the custom layout?

Comment: create a `xml` layout. in that layout put a `TextView` as root layout. and set its `android:gravity="left"` and pass this layout to the `ArrayAdapter` like you giving the `simple_list_item`

Comment: it gives me an error: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView what does that mean?

Comment: i  updated the answer. do not pass like `android.R.layout....` just use `R.layout.myTextView.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" ><br>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/><br>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest.xml

```
<application
....
 android:supportsRtl="true"
...
</application>
```